# Erro no require_once

Tags: php, xampp, recuperação-de-erros

Criei o arquivo `functions.php` e inclui nele a `function add()`, porém quando vou chama-la na página `add.php` pelo comando `require_once` aparece um fatal error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function view() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lester\customers\add.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\lester\customers\add.php on line 3

Seguem códigos:

Esse é do arquivo functions.php

```
    <?php

    require_once('../config.php');
    require_once(DBAPI);

    $customers = null;
    $customer = null;

    /**
     *  Listagem de Clientes
     */
    function index() {
        global $customers;
        $customers = find_all('customers');
    }

    /**
     *  Cadastro de Clientes
     */

    function add() {

      if (!empty($_POST['customer'])) {

        $today = 
          date_create('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));

        $customer = $_POST['customer'];
        $customer['modified'] = $customer['created'] = $today->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        save('customers', $customer);
        header('location: index.php');
      }
    }

    /**      *  Visualização de um Cliente      
     */     

    function view($id = null) {       
        global $customer;         
        $customer = find('customers', $id);     
    }

    ?>

E esse é do arquivo add.php

    <?php 
      require_once('functions.php'); 
      add();
    ?>

    <?php include(HEADER_TEMPLATE); ?>

    <h2>Novo Cliente</h2>

    <form action="add.php" method="post">
      <!-- area de campos do form -->
      <hr />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-7">
          <label for="name">Nome / Razão Social</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer['name']">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <label for="campo2">CNPJ / CPF</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer['cpf_cnpj']">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <label for="campo3">Data de Nascimento</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer['birthdate']">
        </div>
      </div>


Códigos do arquivo view.php
<?php 
    require_once('functions.php'); 
    view($_GET['id']);
?>

<?php include(HEADER_TEMPLATE); ?>

<h2>Cliente <?php echo $customer['id']; ?></h2>
<hr>

<?php if (!empty($_SESSION['message'])) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $_SESSION['type']; ?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['message']; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Nome / Razão Social:</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $customer['name']; ?></dd>

    <dt>CPF / CNPJ:</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $customer['cpf_cnpj']; ?></dd>

    <dt>Data de Nascimento:</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $customer['birthdate']; ?></dd>
</dl>

<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Endereço:</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $customer['address']; ?></dd>

    <dt>Bairro:</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $customer['hood']; ?></dd>

    <dt>CEP:</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $customer['zip_code']; ?></dd>

    <dt>Data de Cadastro:</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $customer['created']; ?></dd>
</dl>
```

Conseguem me dizer o porquê?

Comment: Esse erro não se refere nem a `function add()` que você criou e nem ao arquivo `add.php` e sim a função `view()` e o arquivo `view.php`.

Fica difícil te ajudar dizendo o que está acontecendo sem ver o código. Posta os códigos fontes tbm na pergunta para uma analise melhor.

Comment: Desculpe é que deu erro nos dois arquivos o que tem a função add() e o que tem a função view().

Comment: Entendo, da uma editada ai na sua pergunta, e posta o código que você ta usando dos dois arquivos que está dando erro, e do arquivo que chama pelo comando `require_once`. Não da pra ajudar sem ver o que você fez, entende?

Comment: Seguem códigos.  Esse é do arquivo add.php  <?php 
  require_once('functions.php'); 
  add();
?>

<?php include(HEADER_TEMPLATE); ?>

<h2>Novo Cliente</h2>

<form action="add.php" method="post">
  <!-- area de campos do form -->
  <hr />
  <div class="row">
    </div>
Esse é o do functions.php 
function add() {
if (!empty($_POST['customer'])) {
$today = date_create('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
$customer = $_POST['customer'];
$customer['modified'] = $customer['created'] = $today->format("Y-m-d

Comment: Você precisa colocar os códigos na pergunta e formatado para uma melhor leitura. Nesse link você poderá ver como deve ser feito a formatação:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Desculpe não estou conseguindo formatar a questão é minha primeira participação aqui no fórum. Posso mandar um print da tela? Ajudaria?

Comment: Fiz uma edição na sua pergunta formatando seu código. Quando você inserir algum código fonte na sua pergunta, selecione todo código e aperte as teclas CTRL + K Para pré formatação.

Comment: Aparentemente seu código para a execução da função add() está correto, porem o erro da função view(), ainda não é referente a este código que você postou. Pois ele não aparece a chamada view() conforme a indicação do erro.

Da uma olhada se você está postando o código do arquivo certo sobre o erro que está dando.

Pode publicar prints do erro na sua pergunta também. Quanto mais informações você passar, é melhor.

Comment: Tanto o arquivo add.php e o view.php tem a mesma base inicial e o fatal error sempre aponta apenas para a situação da linha 3 que é onde está a informação da function

Comment: Descobri o erro. Foi coisa muito básica e que fazem a gente perder muito tempo. Criei dois arquivos functions.php um na pasta inc e outro na pasta custommers e os arquivos mencionados aqui estavam fazendo referência a pasta inc, quando deveriam fazer essa referência a pasta custommers. Agradeço pela atenção e tentativa de ajuda.

Comment: O erro que você postou, está estranho, pois ele diz de uma função view() que nem está sendo chamada pelo arquivo add.php. 

Tenta da uma olhada se você postou o erro corretamente, e se não está dando mais nenhum outro erro além desse, pq o erro que você postou e os códigos que foi postado não estão batendo.  

Verifique se o caminho do arquivo functions.php, está correto, e de uma olhada no arquivo de log de erro do php, se apresenta mais alguma coisa, pq o código está correto de acordo com o que está sendo mostrado.

Comment: Revisei as referências e agora deu tudo certo.

Comment: Ahh ok, estava achando bem estranho mesmo, pq o código que você mostrou não estava batendo com o erro. Mas que bom que achou a solução. Abraços

Comment: Gratidão pelo apoio